# Any known particularities/theorems about the serie 2^a_0 + 3*2^a_1 + ... + 3^n * 2^a_n?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Are there any known facts/particularities/theorems about structures as the one below?

$$  3^0 \cdot 2^{a_0} +3^1 \cdot 2^{a_1} + ... + 3^n \cdot 2^{a_n} $$

$$ n, a_0, a_1, .. a_n \in N  $$

Answer (score 1):

This looks similar to numerators of fractions with odd denominator that create specific Collatz cycles. See: [Collatz Conjecture: Iterating with odd denominators or 2-adic integers (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Iterating_with_odd_denominators_or_2-adic_integers)